# Discriminating between a Lambda Parameter List and a Grouping Expression in a Recursive Descent Parser

Tags: parsing, language-design, recursive-descent

I am writing a small scripting language for a project I am working on. I wrote a simple recursive-descent parser for it (similar to the one in the [Crafting Interpreters](https://craftinginterpreters.com/)). I wanted to add support for lambda (anonymous function) expressions and give them the following syntax:

```
let some_func = (param1, param2 = 1) {
    return param1 + param2
}
```

How can I differentiate between the lambda's parameter list and a grouping (parenthesised) expression like the following one, for example:

```
let some_expr = (var1 = 0) // Assignment is allowed as an expression.

let some_func = (param1, param2 = 0) {
    return param1 + param2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda syntax like this (i.e. lambda syntax that starts directly with the parameter list instead of some keyword or symbol that denotes a lambda) is not LL(k) meaning you can't parse it with a finite amount of lookahead.

In other words you can't just switch on the current token as you could for an LL(1) grammar nor can you use an `if` condition of the form `tokens.lookAhead(0).kind == X && tokens.lookAhead(1).kind == Y && ... && tokens.lookAhead(k).kind == Z` as you could for an LL(k) grammar.

Instead, your options are to either use infinite lookahead to see whether there's a `{` after the `)` or to use backtracking, i.e. to try to parse a lambda and if that parse fails, to continue on with the next precedence level (with the `(` still being the current token).

Comment: I have been thinking about this and wondering if checking for a comma in the expression is a good solution. I think it's like checking whether there is a brace after an expression.

Comment: @AbdelfattahRadwan What if there's only one parameter (`(x) {}`)?

Comment: Oh, right. This completely went over my head. Well, I am going with your solution then. Thanks!